# Print the First Row

Tags: r

I have problem to print out the first row from the variable D1

How should I do it?

```
qq <- sample(letters[11:13], 9, replace=TRUE)

V1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 17, 23, 12, 32)

D1 <- data.frame(qq, V1)

D1
```

[image]

Comment: Would this work `D1[1,]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Some options to try for yourself.

```
D1[1,]
```

or

```
head(D1,1)
```